# Angular 8 & ChartJS: Updating donut charts with HTTP Request data

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, morris.js

I'm trying to update a dashboard with responses from HTTP requests I make, but even though the data is correctly fetched from the API, it doesn't update the chart.

- Angular 8.2.14
- Chart.js 2.8.0
- Morris.js 0.5.0

The component is like this:

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';
import { ChartData } from 'angular-morris-js';
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('donutChart1', {static: false}) donutChart1Ref: ElementRef;
    donutChart: Chart;

    constructor(
        private dataService: DataService
    ) {}

    donutChartData: ChartData[] = [];

    public donutChartOptions = {
        colors : ['rgba(218,142,26,0.61)', 'rgba(10,82,166,0.72)', 'rgba(218,26,212,0.61)']
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadChartData();
    }

    loadChartData() {
        this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                const dataGroup1 = response.body.dataOne;
                const dataGroup2 = response.body.dataTwo;

                this.donutChartData.push({
                    label: 'Group 1',
                    value: dataGroup1
                });
                this.donutChartData.push({
                    label: 'Group 2',
                    value: dataGroup2
                });

                const ctx = this.donutChart1Ref.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
                this.donutChart = new Chart(ctx, null);
            }
        );
    }

    async red() {
  
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```html
<div class="col-md-12 center-flex-column" id="donutChart1" mk-morris-js 
    [data]="donutChartData" [options]="donutChartOptions" size=100 
    type="Donut"
></div>
```

(requested by [@yong-shun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8017690/yong-shun)) The response that comes from the API is like this:

```json
{
  "dataOne": 234,
  "dataTwo": 5346
}
```

I'm new to Angular, so if anyone can explain why this is happening and how to fix it, it'll be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, can you show the response return from the API as JSON to the question? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't add the response code here before because it does update other parts of my component, where I'm not using a chart.  (This code is a mimic of the original one, showing only the lines related to the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that just overwriting the property does the trick:

```js
loadChartData() {
        this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                const dataGroup1 = response.body.dataOne;
                const dataGroup2 = response.body.dataTwo;

                this.donutChartData = [
                    {
                        label: 'Group 1',
                        value: dataGroup1
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Group 2',
                        value: dataGroup2
                    },
                ]
            }
        );
    }
```

I'm using `angular-morris-js` so it basically takes care of the update automatically. Hope that this helps another devs too.